# Why use "take" but not "need"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Why you think 'need' is more suitable here?

A: How long will it ( ) you to finish you work?
B: Give me ten more minutes

need→×
take→○

Comment: The correct way to ask this is "Why ***do*** you think...?"

Answer (score 2):

> A: How long will it **take** you to finish you work?

is correct. The basic form is:

> it will take you (five hours)

*take* in this context requires a direct object (you).

However, *need* as used here is intransitive, so you can't write "it will need you". Instead, you have to write:

> How long will you **need** to finish you work?

The basic form here is:

> You will need (five hours)